# Different print formatting between test cases

Tags: c++, printing, format

So I have two test cases below, one showing correct and the other is incorrect. I need to match my incorrect one with the correct one. The print function that is implemented as below. I believe the logic is slightly wrong. But I don't know what to do from here on. I would require your assistance on this. Thank you.

Correct print:

```
********** TestSubscript1 **********
Construct from unsigned char array:
2  4  6  6  8  10  6  12  234  14  16  6  6  (size=13, capacity=16)
using subscript: a[6]
a[6] = 6
```

Incorrect print:

```
********** TestSubscript1 **********
Construct from unsigned char array:
2  4  6  6  8  10 6  12 23414 16 6  6  (size=13, capacity=16)
using subscript: a[6]
a[6] = 6
```

Print function:

```
void Print(const vector<unsigned char>& s)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s.count; i++) 
    {
        std::cout<<std::setw(3)<<std::left<<(unsigned)s.v[i]; 
    }
std::cout<<std::setw(2)<< "(size=" << s.count << ", " << "capacity=" << 
s.capacity << ")";
std::cout<<std::endl; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the width of the number, just put two spaces after the number:

```
std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(s.v[i]) << "  ";
```

And then:

```
std::cout<< "(size=" << s.count << ", " << "capacity=" << s.capacity << ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" output is not limiting itself to using just `std::setw(3)` for all numbers, like you are doing in your output. The output you want can be obtained using `std::setw(3)` for 1-digit numbers, `std::setw(4)` for 2-digit numbers, and `std::setw(5)` for 3-digit numbers,and then omitting the `std::setw(2)` at the end:

```
int getw(unsigned char ch)
{
    if (ch < 10) return 1;
    if (ch < 100) return 2;
    return 3;
) 

void Print(const vector<unsigned char>& s)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s.count; ++i)
    {
        unsigned char ch = s.v[i];
        std::cout << std::setw(2+getw(ch)) << std::left << (unsigned)ch;
    }
    std::cout << "(size=" << s.count << ", " << "capacity=" << s.capacity << ")";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

A simpler way to accomplish the same output is to not use `std::setw` and `std::left` at all. Just write the numbers as-is and then write 2 spaces after each number:

```
void Print(const vector<unsigned char>& s)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s.count; ++i)
    {
        unsigned char ch = ;
        std::cout << (unsigned)s.v[i] << "  ";
    }
    std::cout << "(size=" << s.count << ", " << "capacity=" << s.capacity << ")";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```